# Blur part of the video

Tags: data-science, opencv, python

I am facing issues when trying to blur a video.

The idea is, when I click on a frame, it has to blur the part of the video (as a rectangle).

But, when I run the code, the whole video is appearing blurry. I want the rectangle part of it blurred.
Thank you.

```
def mouse_events(event,x,y,flags,params):
    global x_,y_, clicked
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        x_ = x
        y_ = y
        clicked = True


def blur_rect(win):
    return cv2.GaussianBlur(win, (55, 55), 0)


clicked = False
x_ = 0
y_ = 0
cv2.namedWindow('frame')
cv2.setMouseCallback('frame', mouse_events)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if clicked:
        b = cv2.rectangle(frame, (x_-30, y_-30), (x_+50, y_+50), (0,255,0))             
        blurred = blur_rect(b)

    cv2.imshow("frame", blurred)

    k = cv2.waitKey(2) & 0xFF

    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blur content from a rectangle with Opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58163739/blur-content-from-a-rectangle-with-opencv) There's also a Python answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still facing the same issue. It's supposed to blur the are, I click on. But that's not working

Comment: Please provide your updated code, where you incorporated the ideas from the linked Q&A. Saying *"it's still not working"*, without showing what you've tried, won't help people here to further help you.

Comment: @HansHirse .Thank you. It's working. I didn't apply the blur back on the image.
Thank you.